# How to properly open and close an event-loop in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an asyncio loop `watch_book` nested in `wallet_loop` and `main` I would like to execute in a `for` loop. What is the proper way to do that ?

My problem is that after the first account terminate it's loop and close it, the second account create a new loop but it still complain that the loop is closed. What is the reason for this ?

```
async def watch_book(account, client, market):
    while True:
        ob = await client.watch_order_book(market.symbol)
        if stop():
            break
        await client.sleep(1000)

async def wallet_loop(account, loop, wallet):
    client = getattr(name, exid)({'enableRateLimit': True, 'asyncio_loop': loop, })
    do_more_stuff()
    ws_loops = [watch_book(account, client, market) for market in markets]
    await asyncio.gather(*ws_loops)
    await client.close()


async def main(account, loop, wallets):
    wallet_loops = [wallet_loop(account, loop, wallet) for wallet in wallets]
    await asyncio.gather(*wallet_loops)


for account in accounts:

    wallets = get_wallets()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    if loop.is_closed():
        log.info('Create a new loop')
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    gp = asyncio.wait([main(account, loop, wallets)])
    loop.run_until_complete(gp)
    loop.close()
```

The error I get:

```
2021-07-02 11:45:54.459777 [info     ] Create a new loop

Exception ignored in: <coroutine object throttle.<locals>.run at 0x7f80ce1492b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaa/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/name/async_support/base/throttle.py", line 51, in run
    future.set_exception(excp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 591, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 377, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you run the event-loop inside ``for``-loop and not the other way around? Usually, you want to have one single event-loop that handles all the work – ideally handling all accounts concurrently.

Comment: So, naively ``asyncio.run`` will solve the *error*, but likely isn't an appropriate *solution*.

Comment: `wallets` is different from one account and another, it's the reason why the event-loop is inside the for loop

Comment: Could you please give an example with `asyncio.run` ?

Comment: It's weird because sometimes it doesn't complain that the loop is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the canonical thing there would be just to stick your program in an async function and run it all in the event loop:

```py
async def watch_book(account, client, market):
    while True:
        ob = await client.watch_order_book(market.symbol)
        if stop():
            break
        await client.sleep(1000)

async def wallet_loop(account, wallet):
    client = getattr(name, exid)({'enableRateLimit': True, 'asyncio_loop': asyncio.get_running_loop()})
    do_more_stuff()
    ws_loops = [watch_book(account, client, market) for market in markets]
    await asyncio.gather(*ws_loops)
    await client.close()

async def main(account, wallets):
    wallet_loops = [wallet_loop(account, wallet) for wallet in wallets]
    await asyncio.gather(*wallet_loops)
    
async def main_orchestrator(accounts):
    for account in accounts:
        wallets = get_wallets()
        gp = await main(account, wallets)

asyncio.run(main_orchestrator(accounts))
```

and you could easy even paralelize the processing of all accounts
if that makes a difference  by changing the function to:

```
async def main(accounts):
    await asyncio.gather(*(main(account, wallets) for account in accounts))
```

If for some reason you really need each batch to run in a loop,just replace  `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` for `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()`, nonetheless.